# tex-live build fails with: lacheck.c: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, build, jailbreak, tex-live

While building tex-live using an on-device compiler for jailbroken iOS 13.5, I reached an error where lacheck would fail to build due to a missing `lacheck.c`. The required file is present in the necessary location. Building the lacheck project directly results in no error. I found an instance of this same failure on a legitimate Ubuntu system in the [tex-live mailing list](https://tug.org/pipermail/tlbuild/2018q2/004209.html), but I could not find anyone presenting a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The logs diagnose this error poorly; the real problem is a missing lexer. Thus, I installed flex from sbingner’s repo (and symlinked m4 to `/opt/local/bin/gm4`), and the compilation continued.